# Output List Is Wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, list, oop

I have code like this:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        arrayList.add(new Student("First", "Last", "10"));
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

With Student Class is:

```
public class Student extends Human {
    private String grade;

    public Student(String first, String last, String gradeValue) {
        super(first, last);
        this.setGrade(gradeValue);
    }


    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }


    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
}
```

It's will extends from Human Class:

```
public abstract class Human {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public Human(String first, String last) {
        this.setFirstname(first);
        this.setLastname(last);
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
}
```

Main ideas is I try to create a list 10 students with FirstName LastName and Grade.

Now when I try to print the list in main method, it's show me this: [Student@6fbae5f5].

What I want it show is: First Last 10.

Please note that I try to add more student to the list and it have to show like this:

FirstName1 LastName1 10

FirstName2 LastName2 3

FirstName3 LastName3 7
......................

Comment: Override `toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your Student class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [getFirstname()=" + getFirstname() + ", getLastname()="
            + getLastname() + ", getGrade()=" + getGrade() + "]";
}
```

Comment: Close, but this will not compile.  You will need to change the scope of the fields to protected, or use the getter methods for firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Since each object has `toString()` method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` sign and then the hashcode. In your case, you're printing the object itself.

If you want to print the content of the `arrayList`, you should loop on it:

```
for(Student student : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(student)
}
```

That's after you'll override `toString` in `Student`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add this to Human Class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

2. Add this to Student Class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.toString() + " " + grade;
}
```